# Validation token in both GET and POST parts of Django's view

Tags: python, django

To reset password, user should go to link that contains token:

> example.com/password-change/?token=8125b6da86694a19b5d76f30a04c9db8

In view I have following code:

```
def _get_and_check_password_recovery_token(request, token_hex):
    try:
        token = tokens.get_token(token_hex)
    except Token.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    if token.is_expired():
        token.delete()
        messages.warning(request,
        'Link you use for password recovery became obsolete. Please, request another one.')
        return redirect(reverse('password_recovery') + '?email=%s' % token.user.email)
    return token


def password_change(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.PasswordChangeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            token_hex = form.cleaned_data.get('token')
            new_password = form.cleaned_data['new_password']
            if token_hex:
                token_or_response = _get_and_check_password_recovery_token(request, token_hex)
                if isinstance(token_or_response, Token):
                    user = token_or_response.user
                else:
                    return token_or_response
            else:
                ...
            ...
    else:
        token_hex = request.GET.get('token')
        if token_hex:
            token_or_response = _get_and_check_password_recovery_token(request, token_hex)
            if isinstance(token_or_response, Token):
                token_hex = token_or_response.hex
            else:
                return token_or_response
            form = forms.PasswordChangeForm(initial={'token': token_hex})
        else:
            form = forms.PasswordChangeForm() # TODO Authenticated user changes his password.
    return render_template(request, 'accounts/password_change.html', {'password_change_form': form})
```

As you can see, token must be checked before password change form will be rendered and after it will be submitted by user. So I call method `_get_and_check_password_recovery_token(request, token_hex)` 2 times. It returns response object (is token not found or incorrect) or token. And I don't feel comfortable with it - it's absolutely different objects.

Do you guys see better way to write this code? Is returning of logically different objects  OK for Python?

Comment: This is better suited on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks, @nightcracker, I didn't know about this resource. Will post similar question there in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would raise exception if I cant return token. I would move this token validation to Token class method.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a common use pattern, django included it as part of its auth application and enhanced it in 1.4. See the documentation for [`password_reset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset).

All common templates (password reset email, etc) and token checking is also included.